# Prestashop 1.7.6 category update with simple query lang table

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

what's wrong with the code?

i have a custom module which is handling additional fields in category.
Get, and update data is working good, but not for another language.

Check this out:

```
public function hookCategoryAddition($params)
{
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_h1_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_h1_desc'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id);
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_p_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_p_desc'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id);
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_h1_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_h1_desc_en'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id.' id_lang = 2');
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_p_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_p_desc_en'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id.' id_lang = 2');
}
```

The first 2 lines are updating correctly, but others are not working. Can anyone give my a hint?

Checkout my complete code:

```
class displayBoCategoryTut extends Module
```

{

```
protected $_errors = array();
protected $_html = '';


public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'displaybocategorytut';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.1';
    $this->author = 'KS';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('Dodatkowe pola w kategorii');
    $this->description = $this->l('Pokazuje dodatkowe pola w kategorii');
}

public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install() OR
        !$this->alterTable() OR
        !$this->registerHook('displayBackOfficeCategory') OR
        !$this->registerHook('categoryAddition') OR
        !$this->registerHook('categoryUpdate')
        )
        return false;
    return true;
}

/*public function uninstall()
{
    if (!parent::uninstall() OR
        !$this->alterTable('remove'))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public function alterTable($method = 'add')
{
    if($method == 'add')
        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_lang ADD `top_h1_desc` VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL';
        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_lang ADD `top_p_desc` TEXT NOT NULL';
    else 
        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_lang DROP COLUMN `top_h1_desc`';
        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_lang DROP COLUMN `top_p_desc`';

    if(!Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql))
        return false;
    return true;
}*/

public function top_h1_desc($id_category)
{
    return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT top_h1_desc FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang WHERE id_category = '. (int)$id_category);
}
public function top_h1_desc_en($id_category)
{
    return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT top_h1_desc FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang WHERE id_category = '. (int)$id_category.' AND id_lang = 2');
}

public function top_p_desc($id_category)
{
    return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT top_p_desc FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang WHERE id_category = '. (int)$id_category);
}
public function top_p_desc_en($id_category)
{
    return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT top_p_desc FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang WHERE id_category = '. (int)$id_category.' AND id_lang = 2');
}

public function hookCategoryAddition($params)
{
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_h1_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_h1_desc'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id);
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_p_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_p_desc'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id);
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_h1_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_h1_desc_en'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id.' id_lang = 2');
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_p_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_p_desc_en'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id.' id_lang = 2');
}

public function hookCategoryUpdate($params)
{
    $this->hookCategoryAddition($params);
}

public function hookDisplayBackOfficeCategory($params)
{

    // we need an actual id, otherwise if we are just adding the category this field can be left empty
    if(Tools::getValue('id_category'))
        $top_h1_desc = $this->top_h1_desc(Tools::getValue('id_category'));  
    else $top_h1_desc = '';
        

        if(Tools::getValue('id_category'))
        $top_p_desc = $this->top_p_desc(Tools::getValue('id_category'));
    else $top_p_desc = '';

    if(Tools::getValue('id_category'))
        $top_h1_desc_en = $this->top_h1_desc_en(Tools::getValue('id_category'));
    else $top_h1_desc_en = '';
    

    if(Tools::getValue('id_category'))
        $top_p_desc_en = $this->top_p_desc_en(Tools::getValue('id_category'));
    else $top_p_desc_en = '';
    
    
    

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'top_h1_desc'=> $top_h1_desc,
        'top_p_desc'=> $top_p_desc,
        'top_h1_desc_en'=> $top_h1_desc_en,
        'top_p_desc_en'=> $top_p_desc_en
    ));


    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'backoffice.tpl');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The last part is the WHERE part.

By simply add an `AND` to the last parameter of the method, it should work.

This should be fine:

```
public function hookCategoryAddition($params)
{
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_h1_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_h1_desc'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id);
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_p_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_p_desc'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id);
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_h1_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_h1_desc_en'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id.' AND id_lang = 2');
    Db::getInstance()->update('category_lang', array('top_p_desc' => pSQL(Tools::getValue('top_p_desc_en'))), 'id_category = ' . $params['category']->id.' AND id_lang = 2');
}
```